# How do you delete the last five rows in any worksheet (that could have any number of rows) with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-3.7

So I can delete the last row if I specify it with this of course:

```
ws2.delete_rows(42)
```

But how might I delete the last five rows for example in any given worksheet if there could be any number of rows? Should I determine the max_row and then somehow loop a delete five times? Or is there another way?

I can run this five times to delete the last five rows but is there a way to do this without repeating the command?

```
mr = ws2.max_row
ws2.delete_rows(mr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `delete_rows` and `delete_columns` take an index and an optional number of items. So `ws.delete_rows(ws.max_row-5, 5)` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a for loop:

```
for _ in range(5):
    mr = ws2.max_row
    ws2.delete_rows(mr)
```

Alternatively:

```
for i in reversed(range(ws2.max_row - 4, ws2.max_row + 1)):
    ws2.delete_rows(i)
```

Adding one to the top of the range so that the `max_row` is included in the range, and reversing the range so we start from the last row.